# D3JS: Format Rows

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to create a CSV file in D3JS from a javascript object.  I've found few examples or documentation for the d3.csv.format and d3.csv.formatRows.  The API says that d3.csv.formatRows, for examples, is the opposite of d3.csv.parseRows.

So, to quote from the API for csv.parseRows:

> For example, consider the following CSV file:
>
> 1997,Ford,E350,2.34 2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
>
> The resulting JavaScript
>   array is:
>
> [   ["1997", "Ford", "E350", "2.34"],   ["2000", "Mercury", "Cougar",
>   "2.38"] ]

With this in mind, I assume that if I run the operation:

```
var csved=[["1997", "Ford", "E350", "2.34"],["2000", "Mercury", "Cougar", "2.38"]];
d3.csv.formatRows(csved);
```

This would give me a CSV format for the variable csved.  But it's not working and I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function dsv(url, callback) {
      return d3.xhr(url, mimeType, callback).response(response);
    } has no method 'formatRows'
```

How do I properly setup the d3.format or d3.formatRows syntax?

Comment: Works fine for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/ZPnGG/

Comment: What version of d3 are you using? `console.log(d3.version);`